# looping over a list of file names in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, filenames

Probably a really simple question - but I can't seem to figure it out for Matlab. I would like to import data from a list of files, and save the resulting matrices with a name derived from the original file name. There's quite a few files, so I would like to use a for loop.

In BASH I would write something like:

```
For sample in apple orange guava jackfruit;
do
"$sample"_matrix = someimportfunction("$sample".txt);
done
```

I can import the files one at a time with `dlmread`, I just can't figure out how to loop over the names, sort of the matlab equivelent of `$`.

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping over multiple files in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753284/looping-over-multiple-files-in-matlab)

Comment: "matrices with a name derived from the original file name" is a bad idea. The solution by Nathan below is better: a struct with fields derived from the file names. Don't pollute your workspace with arbitrarily-named variables, it will be very hard to work with.

Answer (score 2):

I think the code snippet below may do exactly what you want.
Of course, you need the files apple.txt etcetera, with numbers in them

```
for sample = {'apple', 'orange', 'guava', 'jackfruit'}
    matrix.(sample{1}) = load([sample{1},'.txt']);
end

matrix = matrix
```

I get the following output:

```
matrix =
  scalar structure containing the fields:

    apple = 1   2   3

    orange =
       1   2
       4   5

    guava =
       1   1   1
       0   0   0

    jackfruit =  17
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your files are in the folder "sfolder".

```
Files = dir('sfolder');
num_files = length(Files);
for i=1:num_files
    fid = fopen(Files(i).name); %do whatever you want now
end
```

This will help you go through each file in a particular directory.